# Vue - pass view data to template component without binding?

Tags: vue.js

In the template part I calling a component. Is there a way I can pass the data without binding like :amount=amount? I tried amount="amount" or amount=amount it doesn't work. The reason I don't want to v-bind is whenever data changed the the value in the component changed. I want to only change by another parameter or prop on v-if in the component tag. The problem is when the amount is changed in parent component then the amount in child component AmountResult gets changed as well. I don't want it to change until finalAmount changed. That's why I put v-if there.

```
<AmountResult v-if="finalAmount !== false" :amount="amount" />
```

Comment: Consider explaining your case further, it's currently unclear why you want to do the thing you described. The exact code could help to understand it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried but it wouldn't display. <AmountResult v-if="finalAmount !== false" :amount="amount" /> It works but if amount changed in parent then in AmountResult component will change it's amount value too.

Comment: It should work using static props like you said you tried. Did you set up the property declaration properly? https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

Comment: If you need a non-reactive copy of initial `amount` value then explicitly copy it on mount inside AmountResult. You didn't explain how exactly it's supposed to work and why, so the exact solution that fits your needs cannot be suggested

Comment: I added the following to my AmountResult component but the data in there will change if the amount is change in the parent. That's the issue. I don't want it to change until the v-if export default {
  props: {
    amount: Number
  },
};

Answer (score 0):

`vuex` will be a good solution for you. All data will be stored in store, and all components will get values from one place

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

const store = createStore({
  state: {
    amount: 0
  },
  getters: {
    amount: state => state.amount
  }
});

// Component

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'amount',
    ])
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there another easier way? Cuz if i've so many components with many different data then I will need to add many data to the store?

Comment: I understand you have a problem in changing the data of the parent component? Everything you pass to the component via `v-bind` is passed by reference. To get new data, make a copy of it before sending it to the component

Comment: My problem is when the amount is changed in parent then the amount in child component AmountResult will changed as well. I don't want to change until I changed finalAmount. That's why I tried to use a v-if

Answer (score 0):

@sparkmix Okay, consider the `emit` and `on` events. The parent component throws the  `this.$emit('setData', 7);` event. The child component receives this event and sets a value or set of values.

```js
var AmountResult = {
  template: '<div>{{value}}</div>',
  data() {
    return {
      value: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setValue(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$parent.$on('setData', this.setValue);
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'amount-result': AmountResult
  },
  created() {
        this.$emit('setData', 7);
  },
})
```